# How delete one item in firebase by key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

the my code to delete one item in firbase in chiled rcipe the method delete all the list item in rcipe on click one item i think that because for loop the get all item not specfic item and delete all of them i don't konw how can delete just one item in list
i went delete the one key just one on click button delete

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
@Override            
public void onClick(View view) {               
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getRootView().getContext());               
builder1.setTitle("Delete post");              
builder1.setMessage("Are you sure that you want delete the post?");              
builder1.setCancelable(true);             
builder1.setPositiveButton(  "Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                          
ref.child("recipe").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {                                 
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for(DataSnapshot uniqueKeySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){                                
    String skey = uniqueKeySnapshot.getKey();                                   
  ref.child("recipe").child(skey).setValue(null);
//by this delete all item in list rcipe refrence                                          //uniqueKeySnapshot.child(String.valueOf(id)).child(skey).getRef().removeValue();
//the not delete any thing                                     
 dialog.cancel();                     
  } }                                  
 @Override                               
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {                             
     Toast.makeText(mContext, "error !"+databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                        
    } });
```

They not do anything when clicking the button delete
i cant insert image

Comment: can you show up your firebase data structure please?

Comment: I posted like answer you can show that and thank you

Comment: where is your firebase data structure? I couldn't find it in your question also one more thing is why you are using for loop instead of setting the null value to the recipe node directly? and I think dialog cancel code is inside for loop isn't? any reason behind that logic?